# Exchange 2010 Mail Moderation - Limit the number of recipients

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, regex

I am trying to create a Transport rule to limit some users from sending e-mails to too many recipients, such action would require mail moderation approval
I had an idea of using `when the message header matches text patterns` and to supply following regex `(@.*?){10}` in order to limit the specific user to send e-mail to more than 10 recipients, but it's not working for me. Am I setting the RegEx expression in a wrong way? Or is it a problem with reading `To` string in message header?
Is there maybe a more convenient way to do such mail moderation?

Answer (score 0):

I think Exchange support simple regular expression, not complex. You could refer to this article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/aa997187(v=exchg.141)

And the recipient number limit can be set on mailbox side: “Recipients > Mailboxes >Properties > Mail flow setting > Delivery Option > Recipient limit > Maximum recipients”.

However, if the message hit the limit, it would return a NDR.

I noticed you seems need an approval and then sent it, I did some research and test, but didn’t find a resolution with a rule for now.